# Why my program not working?

Tags: c

```
#include"stdio.h" 
void print2(int ***b) { 
printf("\n %d \n",***b);
***b=14; 
printf("\n %d \n",***b); } 
void print(int ***b) { 
printf("\n %d \n",***b);
***b=11; 
printf("\n %d \n",***b); } 
void print1(int **b) { 
printf("\n %d \n",**b);
**b=12; 
printf("\n %d \n",**b); }

int main() { 
int p =10; int *q = &p; int **r = &q; int ***a = &r;
printf("\n %d \n",***a); 
print(a); //i.e print(&*a); 
printf("\n %d \n",***a); 
print1(*a); //i.e print1(&**a);
printf("\n %d \n",***a); 
print2(**a); //i.e print2(&***a);
printf("\n %d \n",***a);

return 0; }
```

```
tptr.c:32:8: warning: incompatible pointer types passing
      'int *' to parameter of type 'int ***'
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
print2(**a); //i.e print1(&***a); 1000
       ^~~
tptr.c:2:20: note: passing argument to parameter 'b' here
void print2(int ***b)
```

Comment: I don't see any program!

Comment: What is unclear about the error message?

Comment: What is `a`? What is `print2`? What are their declarations?

Comment: Triple pointer.. wow..you really like the pointer idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused by how the stars means different things in a declaration and in expressions.

When you declare

```
int *q = &p;
```

you get a variable `q` of type `int *` or pointer to integer. The same goes for the declaration of function parameters. A function with the prototype

```
void f(int *q);
```

takes a parameter of `int *` or pointer to int.

When you use the declared variables, you just refer to the variable as `q`, without the stars. So if you want to pass your pointer to integer `q` to the function `f`, which expects a pointer to integer, just say

```
f(q);
```

Here, `q` is the pointer itself. If you want to get at the value pointed at, you must dereference `q` with the dereference operator, the star: `*q`.

The rationale behind the declaration syntax is that "declaration mimicks use", and the (primary) use of a pointer is to get at its contents by dereferencing. (It is a bit similar to declaring arrays with a dimension in square brackets, when you use it by looking up values with indices in square brackets.)

The address-of operator (unary `&`) does the opposite: It takes the address of a variable so that you can store it in a pointer. Your (somewhat contrived)  example does this; the values `p`, `*q`, `**r` and `***a` all refer to the value of `p`.

By way of illustration, I've simplified your example a bit:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print0(int n)
{
    printf("%d\n", n);
}

void print1(int *p)
{
    printf("%d\n", *p);
}

void print2(int **p)
{
    printf("%d\n", **p);
}

void print3(int ***p)
{
    printf("%d\n", ***p);
}

int main()
{
    int p = 10;
    int *q = &p;
    int **r = &q;
    int ***a = &r;

    print0(p);      print1(&p);
    print0(*q);     print1(q);      print2(&q);
    print0(**r);    print1(*r);     print2(r);      print3(&r);
    print0(***a);   print1(**a);    print2(*a);     print3(a);

    return 0;
}
```

See how the `print` functions declare their arguments in the same way as they use it. And the variables with `x` levels of indirection are passed to `printx` unadorned, i.e. without any stars and without address-of operators.

(You can't take the address of a variable directly more than once, because the address is just a number, not a variable with an address itself. You can, of course, take the address indirectly if it is held in a variable, as in your example.)